# Bad Result Formula - Top property setting of field

Tags: crystal-reports

I wish to set the Top property of a field in Format Editor Window> Border Tab> Top Property.

```
if ({report_multiorder_invoice;1.SurchargeID}) = 0 THEN 405 ELSE 739
```

This formula saves correctly without any errors. But when I try to preview the report, it gives me the error "Bad formula result". How can I fix this?

Comment: Yes it is an int value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Top` property in `Format Editor Window > Border Tab` is referring to the *style* of the border, not its position. It's expecting a return type like `crDoubleLine` or `crDashedLine`.

---

I don't see a place to set Y value based on a formula. But if I were you, I'd just make two fields at different heights. Suppress one when `{report_multiorder_invoice;1.SurchargeID} = 0` and suppress the other when `{report_multiorder_invoice;1.SurchargeID} <> 0`